# Rally Java Page Size Ignored

Tags: rally

Here's my code to fetch user stories (over 3000)

```
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
    request.setFetch(new Fetch("Children","Name","Iteration","FormattedID","ObjectID","c_DIteration","c_DPSI"));
    request.setLimit(3000);
    request.setPageSize(3000);
QueryResponse response = this.rest.query(request);
```

In my response, I get this error message

```
"Maximum page size is 200 -- ignoring requested size of 3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rally Webservices API has a server-side maximum allowed Page Size of 200. There's no way to go higher than this.

Comment: so in that case, how do I get values from next pages?

Comment: You're already doing what you need to by setting the limit. The java rest toolkit automatically retrieves all the pages for you behind the scenes iteratively.